# How to Set Event Reminders in Google Calendar for Multiple Users using Python API without Explicit Consent?

Tags: python, django, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm developing an application where I need to set event reminders in multiple users' Google Calendars without explicitly asking for their permission. When exploring the Google Calendar API in Python, I encountered limitations due to privacy and security restrictions.

I'm seeking insights into whether it's possible to set reminders for users' events without direct access or explicit permission for each calendar. Any guidance, code examples, or alternative methods using the Google Calendar API or other approaches that might help achieve this functionality would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google calendar data is private user data it is owned by a user. In order to access private user data you must have the consent of the user.

To use the Google calendar api to access private user data we use OAuth2 to request consent of the user to access that data.

So to address your use case.

> I need to set event reminders in multiple users' Google Calendars without explicitly asking for their permission

You cant you need permission.

Comment: Is there a workaround using third-party tools or services to achieve this without explicit permission? If not, could you explain if there are alternative approaches available if permission from users is obtained?

Comment: There is no work around to getting access to private user data without their permission this would be a huge security risk.  im not sure I understand the statement "alternative approaches available if permission from users is obtained"   if the user grants you permission then you just access the data.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBC_tVJIx5w